# Latexing: Using `program` option to change tex engine does not work

Tags: xetex, sublime-text

I'm using LateXing with Sublime Text 2 for my TeX needs. In the LateXing documentation it says I can choose `xelatex` as the TeX engine by using the following line at the start of my TeX file:

```
% -*- program: xelatex -*-
```

However, it does not work. When I build my pdf using `Ctrl-B` it still uses pdflatex. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: The engine is `xetex` (like `pdftex` or `luatex`)...

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer. I know `xetex` is the engine but the LateXing documentation specifies the use of `xelatex` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `xelatex` is a format and its engine is `xetex`...

Comment: Did you try `%!TEX program = xelatex` as first line of your document (cf. https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/master/README.markdown)?

Comment: I am using LaTeXing not LaTeXTools. That macro does not work in LaTeXing.

Comment: Did you try http://www.latexing.com/support.html ?

Answer (score 1):

I have to use `Cntl+Super+B` (perhaps `Cntl+Windows+B` on PC/Linux?). This brings up a list of possible build systems. I select the `Single Quick Build xelatex` one, and it works. After building once, from then on I can just do "Super-B" (probably `Cntl-B` on Windows/Linux).